# Do you know the term "She is a people's person"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Do you know the term "She is a people's person."?
I cannot find it in a dictionary. My husband says he knows it from Washington, D.C.

Answer (score 9):

I think you (or your husband) might be conflating two different idioms.

"*A* people person" is someone who gets along well with others and is generally well liked,  e.g., "Did you see how Tom handled that irate customer, he is a real people person."

"*The* people's **_**" would refer to the popularity of the thing being described, e.g., "Although other candidates have more experience, he is the people's candidate due to his charisma and ability to relate to the common man."

Comment: Other possessive expressions like "he's a real [man's man](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man%27s%20man)" are similar in form to "the people's candidate" and come to mind; perhaps these contribute to conflation of *people person* with possessive idioms.

Comment: Yes, the distinction is important.

Answer (score 8):

You would more usually hear:

> "She is a people person."

That is, she is a person who gets along with people well.

The noun "people" is being used as an adjective meaning "effective with/interested in people".

By analogy:

> "She is a dog person."
>
> "He is a nature person."
>
> "She is a computer person."

(Although the last two are less common)

Comment: Actually I hear "computer person", meaning someone skilled in use of computers, a lot. Similarly, "Bob is our tax guy", meaning the person who prepares our taxes or is knowledgable about our taxes. Occasionally the idiom is used for all sorts of things, like "Who can I ask about recalibrating the transmogrifier?" "Oh, Fred is our transmogrifier person."

Comment: @Jay was your comment made before, after seeing Fred?

Answer (score 1):

Could it mean in the case of politics that she's **of** the people? Or, **similar/favorable** to her constituency?

Answer (score 0):

I found a few people saying it like that on Youglish, just click through the options [here](https://youglish.com/pronounce/people%27s%20person/english?) until you hear it - actually only found 2 people saying it with a native accent:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lMCGdVAgGQ&t=638s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=424&v=qe8gslqFUMw

Like you, I was also wondering if it's also ok to say:

> people's person

and not

> people person

I guess it's ok just not that common ([people person on Youglish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/people%20person/english?) is way more common) and maybe one day it'll be common enough to make its way into a dictionary at least as slang...

Answer (score -1):

You can find it [in a few dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=people%20person) without the *'s*.

Comment: *Beep beep* - link rot susceptibility detected - possible solution: include content from linked page in post - *blip* - end of report

Comment: What would be the advantage of that?

Comment: re **What would be the advantage of that**: Redundancy in the sense of 'duplication of critical components or functions of a system with the intention of increasing reliability of the system, usually in the [form] of a backup or fail-safe.'